# Committing Files In XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I really need version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250984/do-i-really-need-version-control)

My question is simple enough. When I am in Xcode and right click a file and go down to "Source Control>Commit Selected File...", it brings up a new screen. 
My question is this:
What is committing files for? I'm simply trying to understand the pros and cons.

Thanks!
Jake

EDIT: Now I understand, thanks for the responses!

Comment: Your question is really "why use source control" - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/250984/469210

Comment: I added more information. My reasoning is slightly less generalized than that.

Comment: If you don't understand the benefits of source control, then you probably don't need it... Unfortunately...

Comment: I don't see where your reasoning is less generalized than that at all. All you're saying is "my projects are so small/over so quickly/won't be built upon to merit the small inconvenience of using source control".

Comment: I'm surprised at how you're reacting to this. I simply asked a question, to better help myself to understand it.

Comment: @Jakexx: It's just that this question _has_ been asked many times. Whether you think it's worth the effort is something only you can judge, but you could trust our experience when we say it'll be worth it once your projects aren't very simple and quick anymore. Just like a backup, you'll probably only appreciate it once you've needed it, so it's a good idea to listen to people who've gone through this. Setting up a Git repo in Xcode is literally just one click, and doing a Commit is just one press of alt+cmd+c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, it is possible to draw yourself into a corner: You have a great idea, you change many things, and you notice your idea wasn't as good as you thought. If you had source control, you could just go back to the last working version easily, cleanly, reliably and quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Version control is also a way to back up a working copy of your code. If you don't understand the benefits, you definitely need it.